# Jhipster - Failed to sign in

Tags: mysql, authentication, jhipster

I have included my jhipster .war into an ear with others multiples .war. 
I succeeded to deploy it on my jboss 6.2 server and i can access to the application but i cannot sign in. I have this message : Failed to sign in! Please check your credentials and try again.
It works fine when i launch it alone (using the mvnw command with the command prompt).

Is it a problem with the application-dev.xml ? In this file i have a datasource configuration (url of database, username, password).
Do I need to remove this ? Because i have the same configuration in my application.xml in my ear-project. Or may be the problem comes from somewhere else.

Thanks for your help.

edit :

I can see the red banner which is written "development" when i start the application with mvnw because i started it with the dev profile.
But i cannot see the red banner now when i start my global application deploying on jboss server. So does it mean that it's running with the prod profile ?

I think the problem comes from the jboss server..

Answer (score 1):

do you use ./mvnw -Pprod comand to generate war? 
read this https://jhipster.github.io/production/

Comment: I do not use this command to generate the war. I used the maven war plugin in the pom.xml. So by default it is dev profile.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database structure is correctly sync with your liquibase.
also check file

> /src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml